# What is it called when you bind a method and variable of a class in swift?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm following a book's tutorial on programmatic constraints and decided to read Apple's programming guide afterwards.  I saw the following line of code in Apple's guide which is using a method and a variable in one line of code:

```
// Pin the leading edge of myView to the margin's leading edge
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

I didn't know that it's possible to condense code in this way.  Is there a term for this?

Apologies for sounding like a noob but I would like to know.

Comment: What part of that line are you referring to? Using methods and variables is extremely common. In fact, most lines of code involve calling methods on a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the isActive property being set together with the leadingAnchor or constraint method. @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. If you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor/1500946-constraint) of `constraint(equalTo:)` method, you'll find that it returns an object of type `NSLayoutConstraint` which you can use like any other object ==> You can use its properties and methods in the normal way.

This concept is called *Chaining*, and it's not related to Swift only.